# Formal Two-Column Proof of Kuratowski's Ordered Pair

Tags: set-theory, proof-explanation

So I am writing a paper on logic and set theory and need to prove that Kuratowski's definition of ordered pairs satisfies the biconditional. I know there have been many answers on this but I am trying to do a two column proof of this starting with the pair set axiom and arriving at the two instantiated sets {{a},{a,b}} and {{c},{c,d}}.

From that point it will be two direct proofs where the first assumption will be {{a},{a,b}}={{c},{c,d}}. However, since the axiom of extensionality only goes in one direction, I will have to refer to the substitution property of equality to proceed from this point.

(i) The part of the proof that is supposed to conclude with {a,a}={a} starts with the pair set axiom and then the axiom of extensionality, however, from the point where we state extentionality, we eventually instantiate {a}. To me this seems like we are presupposing {a} is a set in order to show that it is equal to {a,a}. Is this true? Is this the only way to prove the existence of singleton sets? Consider line 3.

1. $\forall x\forall y(\forall u[u\in x\leftrightarrow u\in y]\rightarrow x=y)$ 
   Extentionality
2. $\forall y(\forall u[u\in\{a,a\}\leftrightarrow u\in y]\rightarrow \{a,a\}=y)$ 1 UI
3. $\forall u[u\in\{a,a\}\leftrightarrow u\in\{a\}]\rightarrow x=y$ 2 UI

(ii) My second question is that when referring to the substituition property of equality, what are the abbreviations for these justifications? Would I just put "Sub" in the right hand column?

Comment: $\{$ and $\}$ are not symbols of your language, so you should not write them anywhere in your proof. What you should do instead is to rewrite very carefully the statements you want to prove using only membership as a non-logical symbol. If done properly, this will take care of the problem. Anyway, yes, you cannot talk about $\{a\} $ unless you first prove that it exists.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback and now see that notation which includes '{' and '}' does not look right. However, after giving it more thought, I admit that the goal of this proof is not very clear to me anymore. How do I go about proving that sets with only one object exist? Stripping away the {a,a} and {a} notation is necessary but it leaves me far less confident with what the chronology of the proof is (i.e., prove singletons exists THEN prove they are equal to the set that the pair set axiom admits?)